From which scripture does the story of a king and Brahmin comes?
Does anyone know which scripture has the below story about a king and a Brahmin?
A Brahmin had daughter whom he wanted to get married, since he was poor and can't afford, he decided to steal. 
He entered kings palace for the same, and each time he thought of stealing something, 
his knowledge would come and remembers that stealing gold results in hell etc, this went by whole night.

In morning the king was about to be woken and people were singing his praises to wake him up, 
the king recited a sloka stating how lucky he is to have such luxury, 
but can't find the ending verse for his sloka.
The Brahmin who was hiding under the bed said to complete the sloka - 
at the end when eyes are closed none of the luxury would remain.

What is the name of king and Brahmin?
